# Tensorflow Demo iOS App with different models not working

Tags: python, ios, xcode, tensorflow

**System information**

OS Platform and Distribution: macOS Mojave 10.14.2 Beta

Mobile device : iPhone 8P / IPhone XR

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): SOURCE

TensorFlow version: Newest

Python version: 3.7

Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?: Unknown

Bazel version (if compiling from source): Unknown

GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): Unknown

CUDA/cuDNN version:

GPU model and memory:

**Describe the problem**

Xcode Crashed when I import my models into the TF-Lite example project. I don't know what to do or try to get the models to work.

**Provide the exact sequence of commands / steps that you executed before running into the problem**

1.Import the TFlite and txt files

2.copy the path if needle ( Xcode asks this )

3.rename model_file_name to imported tflite model

4.rename label_file_name to imported txt file

**Any other info / logs**

Loaded model 1resolved reportertensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/squeeze.cc:64 current >= 0 && current < input_num_dims && input_dims->data[current] == 1 was not true.
Node 66 failed to prepare.

Failed to allocate tensors!2018-11-20 13:08:26.664470-0600 tflite_camera_example[9610:2085000] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-11-20 13:08:26.664721-0600 tflite_camera_example[9610:2085000] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

[Xcode Debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75vFt.png)